# How to notify a view in MVVM when the model is changed but no properties changed

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have bound in my list views the items to an observableCollection in my ViewModel (I have two list views, each with their own observableCollection). I also bounded several status bar properties to properties in the ViewModel.

In my view model, I have some special kind of copy/paste functions that copy 'memory'  buffers'. Actually the properties in my view model (and model below) are nothing more than 'pointers' into those memory buffers. When copying I know that properties are changed, but the values themselves are not changed with a setter (so the INotifyPropertyChanged is not called).

How can I refresh the list views?
The status bar is not that difficult because I can call a method in the view model to recalculate the values. However for the list view's data that is quite impractical.

In non MVVM I would just refill them again with data but that is not possible (I think) with MVVM/binding.

Comment: Can you not raise the proper notification when copying these "memory buffers"? You don't always need to rely on property setters.

Comment: Yes like making a non existing string (like property 'Memory') and react on that in my view by refilling the list views? I thought it was considered a dirty trick.

Comment: Can't you just manually raise the PropertyChanged event to tell the UI to update? `RaisePropertyChanged("SomeProperty");`

Comment: @Rachel Yes I can but I thought it was not the proper MVVM way to go.

Comment: The `PropertyChange` notification is supposed to be raised anytime the property has changed, and it sounds like your data has changed even if the reference hasn't, so it's perfectly acceptable to raise the notification yourself.

Comment: @Rachel ... thanks for the clarification. I even can say something about what elements could be changed so I could also raise properties for all (possibly) affected properties, even if not changed?

Comment: You can raise the event, but be careful not to produce an endless circle of notifications. However, if the ordinary setters fire `PropertyChanged` only if an actual change was done, you're usually fine.

Comment: I will try it high level first, then maybe later use more granularity. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your view model you have an ObservableCollection of items (say ObservableCollection). What you need to do is to make sure that **MyItem** (that is, each item in the collection) derives from INotifyPropertyChanged. Then, when you change the items within the collection, fire the PropertyChanged event. The WPF List View will pick it up.

The RaisePropertyChanged described by other commentors is a utility method typically added to VM classes (often, to a common base class of all VM classes). It raises the PropertyChanged event:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged( string prop ) {
    if( PropertyChanged != null ) {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop) );
    }
}
```

As described by other commentors, there is nothing that dictate you raise a PropertyChanged event only from within the setter. Within your Copy method, just call the RaisePropertyChanged with the appropriate property names (you can call it multiple times, for each property that has changed).

EDIT: For the status line, if you want to follow the MVVM design pattern, you shouldn't call methods from the VM to the View (that's a key concept in MVVM: The ViewModel is View agnostic). You should simply call the RaisePropertyChanged method for all the properties that control the status lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... raising multiple events seems like the way to go, since I know in most cases which list view items are changed; and if I don't I can raise them all or raise an event for the complete list view.

Answer (score 1):

Solution according to the comments:

Raise a proper notification when copying these memory buffers: Use

```
RaisePropertyChanged("SomeProperty")
```